Spring Security in Spring Boot 3 - Swagger is broken
I need some help. Below you can see my security config. I want to make localhost:8080/swagger endpoint to be publicly available. When I call swagger ui I am getting Failed to load remote configuration.
What changed in spring boot 3?
@Autowired
    private AuthFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="auth.enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(hs -> hs.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth.requestMatchers("/swagger/**","/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/index.html", "/actuator/health")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .cors(co-> co.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*")); // Allow all origins
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


Was missing "/docs/**", in matchers
